# Classic ASP: VBScript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I've read through a few threads on here about Classic ASP and Javascript, but can not find anything that is totally helpful.

I'm trying to convert my working vb script into Javascript, but am running into problems.

Here is my code:

```
<%
//Declare variables
var formdate, jsia, jsga, yvcia, yvcga, query, myDSN, Connect, rs;

//Provider String and DB location
myDSN = "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.Mappath("/MasterDB.accdb");
//myDSN = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;SERVER=myServerAddress;DATABASE=myDataBase;UID=myUserName;PWD=myPassword";

//Collect data from form
formdate = Request.Form("date");
jsia = Request.Form("jsia");
jsga = Request.Form("jsga");
yvcia = Request.Form("yvcia");
yvcga = Request.Form("yvcga");

//SQL for Query
query = "SELECT * FROM ATTENDANCE;";

//Create and open connection to database
Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
Connect.Open myDSN;

//Create recordset
rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset");

//Open recordset run query in database
rs.Open query, Connect, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic;

rs.AddNew
    rs("Attendance_Date") = formdate;
    rs("JS_Individuals") = jsia;
    rs("JS_Groups") = jsga;
    rs("YVC_Individuals") = yvcia;
    rs("YVC_Groups") = yvcga;
rs.Update;

//Display message
Response.Write("<h1>Your form has been received. Thank you.</h1>");

//Close recordset and database connection
rs.close;
Connect.close;
%>
```

Any tips or documentation I can read on this? I've checked w3schools but they only cover VB script for Classic ASP.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I'm trying to convert my working vb script into Javascript"* - Why??

Comment: I've already written javascript to do form check on the client side, I wanted to add the same functionality to my serverside script. VBScript has limitations, such as not having Try Catch capabilities.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. However, questions like "I can't find documentation" and "please rewrite this program for me in a different language" are off-topic on this site. There is extensive documentation on JScript on the Microsoft pages. If you have a *particular* problem or question, you are welcome to ask it here. Otherwise this question, as it currently is, is out of scope for StackOverflow, sorry.

Comment: My general tip would be not to consult w3schools for anything at all. Despite their name, they are in no way affiliated with the w3c or any official body. They fare in SEO, not in being a useful documentation resource.

Comment: Oh, and last tip: VBScript [does have error handling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/08/19/error-handling-in-vbscript-part-one.aspx). And ASP does support running both VBScript and JScript on the same page. So maybe you'll be better off leaving your working VBS code alone and set up a `<script runat="server" language="jscript">` section to host your user input checking functions. There is [a caveat about running both languages on the same page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/02/19/76438.aspx), but it probably does not apply to your situation.

Comment: Not to be rude, but I did check Microsoft's pages for using Javascript with ASP and have not found much about it at all. I'm not asking for anyone to do my work for me, I was hoping for some advice or tips.

Comment: Thanks for the advice so far though!

Comment: Note that the language that classic ASP pages run is officially called "JScript". Search results might improve by using the proper keyword. In any case, if your JS functions are written in a re-usable fashion then running the same .js file on the client and on the server should be relatively unproblematic.

Comment: Wow, I feel really dumb. I will definitely find better results with Jscript vs Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's all about syntax. JScript got the "+" operator for joining strings, not "&". When calling a method in JScript you must use brackets, while in VBScript it's optional. Other than that, your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ LANGUAGE=JavaScript%>

<%
//Declare variables
var formdate, jsia, jsga, yvcia, yvcga, query, myDSN, Connect, rs;

//Provider String and DB location
 myDSN = "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DATA SOURCE=" +
 Server.Mappath("/MasterDB.accdb");

//Collect data from form
formdate = Request.Form("date");
jsia = Request.Form("jsia");
jsga = Request.Form("jsga");
yvcia = Request.Form("yvcia");
yvcga = Request.Form("yvcga");

var adOpenStatic = 3;
var adLockOptimistic = 3;

//SQL for Query
query = "SELECT * FROM ATTENDANCE;";

//Create and open connection to database
Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
Connect.Open(myDSN);

//Create recordset
rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset");

//Open recordset run query in database
rs.Open (query, Connect, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic);
var fields=Array("Attendance_Date","JS_Individuals","JS_Groups","YVC_Individuals", "YVC_Groups");
var values=Array(formdate,jsia,jsga,yvcia,yvcga);

rs.AddNew(fields,values);
rs.Update();

//Display message
Response.Write("<h1>Your form has been received. Thank you.</h1>");

//Close recordset and database connection
rs.close;
Connect.close;
%>
```